# Can I reset the exim4 configuration to its initial default?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, exim

I have an Ubuntu 8.04 web server on which I had an exim4 installation. I had e-mail set up with a smarthost, but I changed it to local mail only using

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

The problem is now that e-mail is not delivered locally. No e-mail is delivered at all, actually.

Is there a way to completely reset the configuration of exim4, so that it works like in a new installation?

Answer (score 2):

dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config again, and choose the correct options this time :-).

Exim4-config pops up with the dialog you get for dpkg-reconfigure when installed, so there's no real config that's 'like in a new installation'. Ever new installation is different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already tried that with different settings. It always worked fine on a test server, but not on the production server.

There was a problem with the host name. I changed it in /etc/hostname, but hadn't executed

    sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start

yet. Now everything works fine.